# How to run the schema register for Apache Kafka without Confluent env

Tags: apache-kafka, wepay

I am not getting any doc through which I can setup my schema registry for Apache Kafka env only with the help of Confluent. but all I am getting is docs in Confluent env using.

Comment: Are you using apache-kafka(open source) version and now you would like to leverage schema registry?

Answer (score 0):

See if this approach makes sense for your usecase.
[Apicurio registry](https://www.apicur.io/registry/docs/apicurio-registry/1.3.3.Final/getting-started/assembly-intro-to-the-registry.html)

You can host apicurio in Kubernetes and allow client first verify schema before publishing message to kafka.

Some good blogpost outlining on how to use:

 https://itnext.io/stream-processing-with-apache-spark-kafka-avro-and-apicurio-registry-on-amazon-emr-and-amazon-13080defa3be

 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xthbYl7xC74